# How to reference static add method of sqlLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, static, handler

This is my database SQLite code

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "chat";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CHAT = "chat_history";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TT = "tt";
private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
private static final String KEY_MSG = "message";
static SQLiteDatabase db ;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}



// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CHAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHAT + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TT + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MSG + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CHAT_TABLE);
    db = getWritableDatabase();
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHAT);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact

public static void addContact(String tt, String type, String msg) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TT, tt); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, type); // Contact Phone Number
    values.put(KEY_MSG, msg);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CHAT, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
 }
```

I have a static handler for transferring messages from one activity to another.

These are to be stored in the database.
The above database class works fine if the remove the static from handler.

But i am not able to use it when handler is static.

How do i make static reference to my database class?

```
public DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

The error which i get on making the db static 
is cannot use this in static context

Comment: remove the static modifier `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); db.open(); db.addContact(name,type,message)`

Comment: I cannot remove static...it is of too much use

Comment: get to know about the use of static modifier and use it according to your needs if its of too much use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, I think you shouldn't do your database class static. Instead of using "this" you should use a static value of your context to be able to create it inside your `Handler`. Something like this:

```
private static Context mContext;

private static Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = this;

}
```

If you use this approach you should remove the static modifier from your database class.